# Multiple IF conditions in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Please help me in shortening the following code:

```
If Val(TB.Text) = 0 Then
    OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.Gray
ElseIf Val(TB.Text) = 1 Then
    OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.Lime
ElseIf Val(TB.Text) = 2 Then
    OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.Red
ElseIf Val(TB.Text) = 3 Then
    OvalShape1.BackColor = Color.White
End If
```

Comment: You could keep the colors in an array and check once if the value is within the bounds. If it is then do `OvalShape1.BackColor = colors[TB.Text]`. Conceptually anyway; I'm no vb guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it:

```
Dim colors As System.Drawing.Color() = {Color.Gray, Color.Lime, Color.Red, Color.White}

OvalShape1.BackColor = colors(Val(TB.Text))
```

But it is better to add some validation to cover for invalid inputs in `TB.Text` that would lead to runtime errors. Here is longer, but better code:

```
Dim colors As System.Drawing.Color() = {Color.Gray, Color.Lime, Color.Red, Color.White}
Dim value as Integer

value = Val(TB.Text)
If value >= 0 And value <= colors.GetUpperBound(0) Then
    OvalShape1.BackColor = colors(value)
End If
```

Comment: thank you trincot.. it worked, just had to alter declaration since value of type System.Drawing.Color can not be converted to 'Long"...

Comment: ... and I now see you posted the correction as a separate answer. It would be nice though to give the credit and accept as answer.

Comment: Being new to this forum, I didn't know about that.. Just removed my answer and accepted yours.. Apologies..

Comment: Many thanks, Prashant! The responsiveness on this site is driven by these credits.